# Django admin - display TabularInline if "something"

Tags: python, django

I need to display **Bar** like TabularInline in the **Foo** admin, but only if **lorem_ipsum** is true.

Example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    lorem_ipsum = models.BooleanField(...)


class Bar(models.Model):
    Foo_obj = models.ForeignKey(Foo, relatet_name='foo_obj')
    ...
```

It's possible to do in the admin?

Ps. I don't want use proxy and override queryset() for each proxy.

Comment: What if some Foo object are True but some false False?

Comment: you have to def a method for FOO which going to return True base on your condition. and use that method as attribute in your admin.